# Dropzone JS: Integrate Cropper JS on added file. How to call done function to complete 'transformFile' parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I created an image uploader in laravel using dropzone js and thinking to integrate cropper js to crop image right before upload. So I tried the cropper js integration first, it's all good, work well as I expected. But I want to submit image together with my form, so I put two additional option:
`autoProcessQueue: false, autoQueue: true`.

And I have to call the transformFile method on addedfiles, here's my code on dropzone only:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzoneDragArea", { // Make the dropzonedragndrop class a dropzone
   url: "/registerUser", // Set the url
   transformFile: function(file, done) {
       console.log('done', done);
       // Create Dropzone reference for use in confirm button click handler
       var myDropZone = this;
       
       // Create the image editor overlay
       var editor = document.createElement("div");
       editor.style.position = "fixed";
       editor.style.left = 0;
       editor.style.right = 0;
       editor.style.top = 0;
       editor.style.bottom = 0;
       editor.style.zIndex = 9999;
       editor.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
       document.body.appendChild(editor);

       // Create confirm button at the top left of the viewport
       var buttonConfirm = document.createElement("button");
       buttonConfirm.className = "btn btn-success";
       buttonConfirm.style.position = "absolute";
       buttonConfirm.style.left = "10px";
       buttonConfirm.style.top = "10px";
       buttonConfirm.style.zIndex = 9999;
       buttonConfirm.textContent = "Confirm";
       editor.appendChild(buttonConfirm);
       buttonConfirm.addEventListener("click", function() {
           // Get the canvas with image data from Cropper.js
           var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
               width: 256,
               height: 256
           });
           // Turn the canvas into a Blob (file object without a name)
           canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
               // Create a new Dropzone file thumbnail
               myDropZone.createThumbnail(
                   blob,
                   myDropZone.options.thumbnailWidth,
                   myDropZone.options.thumbnailHeight,
                   myDropZone.options.thumbnailMethod,
                   false, 
                   function(dataURL) {
                       // Update the Dropzone file thumbnail
                       myDropZone.emit('thumbnail', file, dataURL);
                       // Return the file to Dropzone
                       done(blob);
                   }
               );
               // Return the file to Dropzone
               done(blob);
           });

           // Remove the editor from the view
           document.body.removeChild(editor);
       });

       var buttonReset = document.createElement("button");

       buttonReset.className = "btn btn-warning";
       buttonReset.style.position = "absolute";
       buttonReset.style.left = "120px";
       buttonReset.style.top = "10px";
       buttonReset.style.zIndex = 9999;
       buttonReset.textContent = "Reset";
       editor.appendChild(buttonReset);
       buttonReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
           document.body.removeChild(editor);
       });

       // Create an image node for Cropper.js
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
       editor.appendChild(image);
       
       // Create Cropper.js
       var cropper = new Cropper(image, { aspectRatio: 3/4 });
       console.log('test');
   },
   thumbnailWidth: 112,
   thumbnailHeight: 150,
   parallelUploads: 1,
   maxFilesize: 1,
   maxFiles: 1,
   dictFileTooBig: `File terlalu besar {{filesize}} MB. Ukuran maksimal: {{maxFilesize}} MB.`,
   previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
   autoProcessQueue: false,
   autoQueue: true, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
   previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
   clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
   params: {
       '_token': token,
   },init: function(){
       myDropzone = this;
       this.on("addedfiles", function(file) {
           // get this code below from browsing through google
           doneCounter = 0;
           doneFunction = (function(_this) {
               return function(file, paramName, fileName) {
                   return function (transformedFile) {
                       formData.append(paramName, transformedFile, fileName);
                       if (++doneCounter === file.length) {
                           return _this.submitRequest(xhr, formData, file);
                       }
                   };
               };
           })(this);
           // get this above code from browsing through google
           this.options.transformFile.call(file, doneFunction(file, this._getParamName, file[0].upload.filename));
       });
```

With that code, I feel that I have wrong on doneFunction. I've got this error message on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at File.transformFile (photoUploader.js:84)
    at b.<anonymous> (photoUploader.js:125)
    at b.value (dropzone.min.js:1)
    at b.value (dropzone.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.drop (dropzone.min.js:1)
transformFile @ photoUploader.js:84
(anonymous) @ photoUploader.js:125
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
drop @ dropzone.min.js:1
```

Anyone can help me on getting "done function" to put on transformFile parameter?! Appreciate your help. Thank you